# sub query and common table expression

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

Hi I want to understand how to structure query in subquery vs common table expression: See example below.

**Write a query to count deduped records in the health.user_logs table**

Approach 1: use sub query: select count statement is in the beginning

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT *
  FROM health.user_logs
) AS subquery;
```

Approach 2: use common table expression: select count statement is in the end?

```
WITH deduped_logs AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT *
  FROM health.user_logs
)
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM deduped_logs;
```

When to decide if the select count statement should be in the beginning or in the end?

Comment: doesn't matter... it's a matter of preference...

Comment: 'DISTINCT *' is an oxymoron (or a tautology, depending upon your point of view)

Comment: A sub-query in the `FROM` clause is called _derived table_. And a `WITH` clause can have one, or several sub-queries, often called common table expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Most often this is about personal preferences, i.e. what you like better and consider more readable.

```
SELECT ...
FROM
(
  SELECT ...
  FROM some_table
  WHERE ...
) AS subquery
JOIN another_table ON ...
```

and

```
WITH
(
  SELECT ...
  FROM some_table
  WHERE ...
) AS subquery
SELECT ...
FROM subquery
JOIN another_table ON ...
```

are equivalent and one is as good as the other. One advantage with the `WITH` clause is that you can access the same subquery more than once:

```
WITH
(
  SELECT ...
  FROM some_table
  WHERE ...
) AS subquery
SELECT ...
FROM subquery s1
JOIN subquery s2 ON s2.type = s1.type AND s2.id < s1.id
```

Another advantage is that you can build your query step by step without nesting subquery in subquery (at least not visibly), so the query may be considered more readable:

```
WITH all_jobs AS (...)
   , technical_jobs AS (... FROM all_jobs ...)
   , well_paid_technical_jobs AS (... FROM technical_jobs ...)
SELECT *
FROM well_paid_technical_jobs
WHERE ...
```

vs.

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
  SELECT ...
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT ...
    FROM 
    (
      ...
    ) all_jobs
    WHERE ...
  ) technical_jobs
  WHERE ...
) well_paid_technical_jobs
WHERE ...
```

Comment: So I tried to use the WITH clause to create a query to identify duplicate records that have a frequency of more than 1 as follows but it doesnt work:

```

WITH
(
select
id,
log_date,
measure,
measure_value,
systolic,
diastolic,
count(*) as frequency
from health.user_logs
group by
id,
log_date,
measure,
measure_value,
systolic,
diastolic
) AS distinctusers
select * from distinctusers
having count (*)>1
order by frequency desc
limit 10;
```

Comment: 1. You've got the syntax wrong. Not `with (...) as alias`, but `with alias as (...)`. 2. `group by id`??? Are there duplicate IDs in your table? If a column is called ID, it should uniquely identfy a row and there should hence be a unique constraint on that column. 3. `having count () > 1` is invalid. You probably mean `having frequency > 1`.